# DocumentDB: Coldfusion Returning 401 Authorization error

Tags: node.js, azure, coldfusion, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect Azure DocumentDB/CosmosDB through the coldfusion but receiving 401 authorization error. I already installed the certificates but still having the same issue. I tried with PHP, Nodejs, both are performing well except ColdFusion. Also tried using coldfusion script but the error remains same. Here is the code what I wrote:

```
<cfset x_ms_date="#GetHttpTimeString(now())#"/>
<cfset br = "#chr(13)##chr(10)#">
<cfset signStr="GET#br#dbs#br##br##x_ms_date##br##br#" />
<cfset strBase64ValueKey="BASE64_ENCODED_MASTER_KEY" />
<cfset key=ToString(ToBinary(strBase64ValueKey))/>
<cfset x=ToBase64(hmac(LCase(signStr),LCase(key),"HMACSHA256"))>


<cfhttp method="GET" url="https://APP_URL.documents.azure.com/dbs" throwonerror="Yes">
<cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="#URLEncodedFormat("type=master&ver=1.0&sig="&x)#">
<cfhttpparam name="x-ms-date" type="header" value="#x_ms_date#">
<cfhttpparam name="x-ms-version" type="header" value="2017-02-22">
</cfhttp>
<cfoutput>
    #cfhttp.fileContent#
</cfoutput>
```

Here is the response from the above code:

> {"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can't
>   serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as
>   per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the
>   following payload to sign: 'get\ndbs\n\nthu, 08 feb 2018 19:52:03
>   gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: aab94428-63a0-4eb7-807b-SOMETHING,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.186.1"}

What is the wrong with that code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This would work if you change the code to something like this:

```
<cfset x_ms_date = GetHttpTimeString(now()) />

<cfset strBase64ValueKey = "BASE64_ENCODED_MASTER_KEY" />
<cfset br = chr(10)>
<cfset signStr = "GET#br#dbs#br##br##x_ms_date##br##br#" />

<cfset secret = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec' ).Init(BinaryDecode(strBase64ValueKey, "Base64"), 'HmacSHA256')/>
<cfset mac = createObject('java', "javax.crypto.Mac")/>
<cfset mac = mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")/>
<cfset mac.init(secret)/>
<cfset x = mac.doFinal(LCase(signStr).GetBytes())>
<cfset sig = BinaryEncode(x, "Base64")>
<cfset token = URLEncodedFormat("type=master&ver=1.0&sig=#sig#")>


<cfhttp method="GET" url="https://APP_URL.documents.azure.com/dbs" throwonerror="Yes">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="#token#">
    <cfhttpparam name="x-ms-date" type="header" value="#x_ms_date#">
    <cfhttpparam name="x-ms-version" type="header" value="2017-02-22">
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>
    #cfhttp.fileContent#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It'd help others to include an explanation of what changes were made and why it works :) (Also, recent versions of CF support HMAC natively).